# static inline __attribute__((always_inline)) for a header only library?

Tags: c, clang

```
static inline __attribute__((always_inline))
```

If I use this before every function definition in a header will it guarantee inlining and will unused functions not be in the translation unit it’s included in?

Comment: Some functions cannot be inlined at all -- e.g. recursive ones, or ones you take address of. Clang should issue a warning about that though.

Comment: But outside of those, is this a safe way to go?

Comment: using it in *every function definition* is a bad idea. Not all functions need to be inlined, and inlining all will introduce code bloat which may affect performance negatively

Comment: let the compiler decide whether to inline or not. the compiler is smarter than you  (in 99% of cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `static inline __attribute__((always_inline))` for a header only library?

No, just `static inline`. `static` so that the function can be in a header, `inline` to silence compiler warnings. No `__attribute__`, as it would make the library non-portable  with a setback that long functions will be inlined increasing code size.

Let the user use inlining that he wants - `-O3` will inline more, `-Os` will inline less.

> f I use this before every function definition in a header will it guarantee inlining

Yes.

> will unused functions not be in the translation unit it’s included in?

They will be in the translation unit. They are defined in that translation unit.

Unused `static` functions will not be included in the resulting object code coming from compiling that translation unit. This is unrelated to using `__attribute__((always_inline))`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, there is no guarantee, that a function will be inlined. The inline keyword is just a hint for the compiler.

From the Clang reference (`always_inline`):

> Inlining heuristics are disabled and inlining is always attempted regardless of optimization level.
>
> Does not guarantee that inline substitution actually occurs.

**References**:

- [cppreference.com - inline function specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/inline)
- [Attributes in Clang - always_inline, __force_inline](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#always-inline-force-inline)
- [Clang Static Analyzer - Inlining](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/analyzer/developer-docs/IPA.html)